# App for sharing words between PC web browser and Anroid device

Tags: applications

I often surf www on my PC. For foreign language pages I use Firefox add-on [gTranslate 0.9](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/gtranslate/). It's quite convenient, just highlight a word in browser, right click, translate.

But I'd like to remember those words (along with its translation) in cloud and then have an application on my Android device which shows those words so I can learn my vocabulary.

Is there any similar application somewhere?

Eventually it can be only bare foreign word without translation, as it could be translated down in the Android application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Anki. It's a flashcard program using spaced-repetition to help you learn vocabulary and other similar things. There's a [free desktop app](http://ankisrs.net/), as well as a compatible free Android app called [AnkiDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ichi2.anki). The two apps can sync to each other through "the cloud", so you could use it to add cards on your PC when you find a new word, then learn those flashcards on your Android device.

Anki supports non-Latin characters and scripts, and you can add images too (if you want to learn to recognise a sign, for instance). You can even download *decks* of cards made by other users.

Comment: +1 First thing I thought about as solution for this question was AnkiDroid.

Comment: It's almost it. Almost because there's no browser add-on to easy adding new cards.